# Will salvaging an item with a sigil always reward the sigil?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have quite a few items with sigils in my inventory (i.e. Minor Sigil of Corruption gives +5 condition damage with every kill). I'd like to salvage the items for the sigils and then reapply the sigils to whatever weapon I'm currently using, but I'm concerned that I may lose the sigils if I do this.

If I salvage an item with a sigil, am I guaranteed to be rewarded with the sigil?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, if you read the description of the salvage kit, it tells you the percentage chance for it to recover upgrades. The best non-gem-store salvage kit has an 80% chance to recover items in sockets.

Here are all the salvage kits:

```
Crude        - "small chance"
Basic        - 20%
Fine         - 40%
Journeyman's - 60%
Master's     - 80%
Black Lion   - 100%
```

The Black Lion salvage kit can be bought from the gem store for 300 gems, and can also occasionally be found in Black Lion chests.

[Source](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Salvage)